# Configure eth1 to stop using dhcp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, networkcard

How do I configure eth1 (via terminal commands) to stop using DHCP. That is, if I had the ability to use the GUI, I would select the MANUAL setting.

Comment: Can you post the output of `nmcli dev status`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Ubuntu:

Edit /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(enter your ip here)
        netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(enter gateway ip here,usually the address of the router)
```

Then edit /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(enter your dns server ip)
nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(enter your alt dns)
```

Restart the network and you should be oki.

Comment: It doesn't work, let me provide more details. I am remotely connecting into a linux box. This box has 3 network interfaces, the one I need to use is eth1. This interface is going to talk to a hardware device, so I need to set the ip address to one in the same subnet as the device, when I do so, it is removed after a few seconds because the interface is using dhcp. I've edited the file as suggested but it does not help.

Comment: Well please post the contents of your config gile. Notice I've used eth0 as device on my example, did ou replace it by eth1?

Comment: Looks like his system is using NetworkManager - he has a comment below about `interfaces` containing only entries for lo0. Is there a way, using `nmcli`, say, to have NetworkManager stop managing eth1 ?

Answer (score 1):

To set the interface static add to /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
```

To leave the interface unconfigured add those lines:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
```

Comment: Modifying /etc/network/interfaces did not achieve anything, the problem was that even if the box was being run remotely with a terminal window, the OS had been installed with a GUI running on it that I was not aware of, which had a daemon that was bringing stuff back to what it was before. All I had to do was plug a monitor and a keyboard to the box and do the changes using the GUI interface.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: There is nothing there, only "auto lo" and "iface lo inet loopback". Not a clue what to add.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete answer, see chaos' answer.